URL string interpolation with Amazon Connect Views
In Amazon Connect, I can use a prebuilt Detail view to show a link:
Attribute Bar JSON:
[
  {
    "Label": "Billpay Code",
    "Value": "$.Attributes.BillpayCode",
    "ResourceId": "$.Attributes.BillpayCode",
    "Copyable": true,
    "LinkType": "external",
    "Url": "https://example.com/$.Attributes.BillpayCode"
  }
]

With an attribute value of ABC, the resultant URL is https://example.com/"ABC".  How can I avoid quotes being added?

I would have thought that would work, but if not then I'd try setting an attribute to the full url and then reference that directly. e.g. use a set attributes block to set the User Defined URL attribute to https://example.com/$.Attributes.BillpayCode the use $.Attributes.URL in the json.
